# PHP: 301 Redirect Page while maintaining GET variables

Tags: php, redirect

I have a page that has been replaced with a new page of a different name, is there a way to redirect this page while maintaining _GET variables passed in the url.

what I have right now:

`old-page.php`

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/new-page.php', true, '301');
```

when users navigate to a url like `old-page.php?var=1` they are taken to `new-page.php` , how can I get it to redirect them to `new-page.php?var=1`? the query string can be several different things, so I'd like a solution that can work w/ any combination of get variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/new-page.php'
   .(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])?'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']:''),
   true, '301');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use sessions:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['your var'] = "value";
```

or you can pass it in your redirect url

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/new-page.php?key=value', true, '301');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, you can use the almighty [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). This way, you can rewrite everything - `GET`, `POST` and more.

If you want to do it in PHP, in order to make it right(tm), you need to consider `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` as well. Just because when running HTTPS on a custom port, you maybe do not want to redirect to HTTP using default port.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like:

```
$parse = '';

foreach($_GET as $i => $j)
    $parse .= "$i=$j&";

$parse = (strlen($parse) > 0 ? "?" : "") . substr($parse, 0, -1);

header("Location: old-page.php$parse");
```

Comment: This works in the real world, but it still violates the specification, as the given resource is invalid - it is missing a scheme and a host.

Comment: I'm not great with PHP so if you could send me a resource explaining what you just said that would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a PHP issue, but HTTP-related, see [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30).